# Best way to sort part of a list (Java)

Tags: java, sorting

I need to sort the end of a list `[6, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 0] --> [6, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 5]` which can be easily done with arrays `Arrays.sort(sequence, i, sequence.size());` but how would I do it with lists when Collections.sort doesn't allow start and end parameters?

Comment: pass list.sublist() in collection.sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass sublist in Collection.sort()..

```
List<Integer> a= Arrays.asList(6, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 0);
Collections.sort(a.subList(3,a.size()));
a.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```